# How do I Write a .wav file on C++ using the socket layer in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, audio, tcp, wav

I am trying to send wav files in C++ via TCP on Linux over a socket but I don't understand how a wav file can be read correctly.

My goal is to read the file on the client into a char array, send it with "write()" to the server, and the server should write the data into a local wav file again.

I read the .wav file like this:

```
////////////define socket - left out for simplicity

ifstream file ("audio.wav", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate); //open .wav file
char * buffer; //declare data buffer, should contain .wav data to write to socket
streampos filesize; //size of file
int n; //number of written bytes

//if file opened correctly, read content and write to socket
if (file.is_open()){
    filesize = file.tellg();
    buffer = new char [filesize];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read (buffer, filesize);
    file.close();
    n = write(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
 }
```

On the server, this returns the array "RIFF" of length "4", so its part of the header of the wav file.

**How can I read the whole .wav file content correctly for writing to the TCP socket?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simple: `filesize` is size of the file in bytes. However, `sizeof(buffer)` is only 4 on a 32-bit OS. Modify your code like this:

```
if(file.is_open()) {
    filesize = file.tellg();
    buffer = new char [filesize];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read (buffer, filesize);
    file.close();
    n = write_all(socket, buffer, filesize); // use filesize here
    delete[] buffer; // !!
}
```

To simplify processing on the other side, you may want to send `filesize` first to avoid parsing of the RIFF header to know how many bytes to accept. I would also suggest allocating a smaller buffer and reading several times to send the larger files over:

```
if(file.is_open()) {
    filesize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    uint32_t remains = filesize;
    write(socket, &remains, sizeof(uint32_t));
    // write 4B with size of the file (optional)

    buffer = new char[(filesize > 4096)? 4096 : filesize];
    // only up to 4k buffer to avoid running out of memory

    n = 0;
    while(remains > 0) {
        int chunk = (remains > 4096)? 4096 : remains;
        // decide how much to read in at one time (not more than size of the buffer)

        file.read(buffer, chunk);
        n += write_all(socket, buffer, chunk);
        // read a chunk and write it to the socket

        remains -= chunk;
        // update number of bytes that remains to be transferred
    }
    // send the file several times

    file.close();
    delete[] buffer; // !!
}
```

You may notice the use of a helper function `write_all`. That is required, because the socket might get full and then `write` will not write all the data given to it. It could look like this:

```
size_t write_all(int socket, const char *buffer, size_t size)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    while(size > 0) {
        size_t written = write(socket, buffer, size);
        if(written == -1)
            return written; // handle errors
        n += written;
        size -= written;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`buffer` is of type `char*`, so `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of an ordinary data pointer on your platform. So you're writing 4 or 8 bytes (assuming ordinary plateform) to your socket.

You need to put `filesize` in the `write` call instead of `sizeof(buffer)`.

(`sizeof` is a compile-time construct. It's evaluated when your code is compiled. It can't return a size that's determined at runtime.)

Answer (score 2):

In the line `n = write(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` the value of the last buffer becomes the size of a pointer on your platform. Since only four bytes are sent, I will assume that you are either on a 32-bit platform or compiling the application in 32-bit mode.

Replacing `sizeof(buffer)` will only be a partial solution since `write()` may not write all the data at once. You will need to check the  value returned from `write()` and keep record of how many bytes have been written to the socket.

Answer (score 1):

I used [sndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) for handling wav files.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this, although I'd prefer without external libraries.

Comment: If it is just about reading the file and sending its content over a tcp socket to a remote machine you won't need this library. I just stumbled over the word "parsed" in your first sentence and assumed that you would actually need to parse the wav file before sending. As I understand your question now, you just want to send some piece of arbitrary data -- which happens to be a wav file in your case -- over the network.